# Imported modules recognised in IDLE but not in Atom

Tags: python, pyspark, atom-editor, python-module, python-idle

Atom & IDLE are both running Python 3.7.1 as shown by

```
$ python3 --version
```

but Atom doesn't recognise any of the modules that have been installed.

I've tried `pip install` in both programs to no avail. For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Spark Example") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

This gives the following error when importing from Pyspark:

> ImportError: No module named pyspark.sql

Comment: Check that both are running the same Python interpreter (not only the same Python version) with `$ which python3`.

Comment: @jfaccioni Can I run a terminal command in Idle?

Comment: From inside a Python shell (like IDLE),, write `import sys` and then `sys.executable` to check where the Python interpreter is located.

Comment: Thanks, here are the results: Atom terminal: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3', OS terminal: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Idle: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7' but in the process I discovered that the Atom terminal will load the pyspark module, but the .py file will not. Does this help or confuse the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Atom is a "hackable" text editor. It can mimic code and some environments. A spark session is out of its scope. There are plug-ins with additional features (like the terminal for example). There is one plug-in called pyspark, try it and see if it has what you are looking for.